# Is callback function necessary to asynchronous

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

Asynchronous functions like setTimeout, Fetch and setInterval all have pattern like having call back function. Ones our requested data available we can manipulate them by using That callback function. My question is whether can we consider callbacks are always asynchronous or not?

Comment: Callback is just a normal function which is executing synchronously.

Answer (score 2):

No.

The callback passed to, for example, [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is resolved synchronously.

Comment: Thanks for your help and time:)